# How to implement load supply takeover in an MCU circuit with battery backup supply?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, power-electronics, design

I'm designing a circuit for my project and I want to simplify my work by using the MCU's ([heltec wireless stick](https://heltec.org/project/wireless-stick-lite/)) integrated battery management, but I don't know if this is viable.

I need some components to be powered either directly from USB or from a battery when the power goes down. But I'd like to charge the battery using the existing MCU's PMS.

Or how else can I do this if the integrated PMS can't be used?

Comment: There are many questions and answer posts on this site relating to this requirement. A site search should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supply switch for your external load can be implemented using a logic level P-MOSFET and a diode.
**BUT:** This is only a part of the solution, many charger circuits embedded in MCU modules don't have a proper undervoltage detection and don't disconnect the battery when empty! This circuit assumes, that this problem is *handled* somewhere.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fezpLU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- If USB supply is available, the FET is not conducting, the gate voltage is above the drain voltage. The external load is supplied via D1. This could also be a Schottky type.
- Without USB supply the gate voltage relative to drain is sufficient to turn it on. The body diode of the FET defines the drain voltage to around Ubat - 0.7 V and R2 pulls the gate down to 0 V.
- USB does not allow big capacitive loads, so the external load should not contain more than 1-2 uF.
- This solution violates the USB rules because it may immediately draw 200 mA before the power requirements are declared by the USB device. This is bad style and may cause problems if connected to a hub. However, PC hosts typically tolerate this and in a private project this is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

The sharing of Vbat and Vusb is possible in the load but it neglects so many details.

The redundancy could be in the charger such that it senses battery current independent of charger total load current and provides Vbat to load always whether Vusb is available or not.

Your method implies you will ensure no crossfeed from Vusb to Vbat in your load, which is not defined. That can be done with an IC to detect which voltage is higher to drive discrete low-side Nch FETs or roll your own high-side switches.

You might want to start with a design spec that lists all the power features for dual supply and protection of the load and battery with measurable values so you can verify your design by testing (DVT) and confirm it meets your spec.

---

With link added in comment(which ought to have been included in question)  It appears the board can switch between Vbat or external power.

[image]

Comment: https://heltec.org/project/wireless-stick-lite/ this is the MCU that will be doing the power management.